# How to stop the asynchronous calling using ES6 promises

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am familiar with ***bluebird*** promises, In that ***.each()*** is used to get all records at once and iterate one one record, so that I am able to pass that one record into another function and getting data. But in ES6 I don't find such function like (.each()). Please provide me any solution for synchronous execution.Thanks..

Comment: Are you looking for `Promise.all`?

Comment: I am looking for Promise.resolve()

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.each(array, f)` likely isn't different enough from `Promise.all(array.map(f))` to warrant its own function in es6.